# Does a conjugation "piaccioni" of the verb "piacere" exist?

Tags: verbs

In my Italian textbook I encountered these two sentences:
"Ti piacciono i romanzi gialli?" and "Ti piaccioni i film gialli?"
I thought "piaccioni" was an error, but I am finding the "piaccioni" version when searching Google.

Comment: I think it's an error.

Comment: There is no way *piaccioni* can be a verb in any conjugated form, notwithstanding the “examples” proposed at http://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/piaccioni

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the previous answer, "piaccioni" is a spelling error.  If you find it on Google, could it be that maybe you are seeing "piacioni"  with one "c" ?  If so, that's the plural of the word "piacione" [= someone who is likable, someone who likes to please everyone]

Comment: I searched for the word "piaccioni" with double c on Google. So it's definitely a misspelling of the verb "piacciono".

Comment: More than a spelling error, I would call it a typo / misprint.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely a spelling mistake, there is only one correct form and it's **piacciono**. Probably you can find some wrong examples on the internet because it's a word easy to mistype, anyway I've run a fast check and the vast majority of examples you can find display the correct form **piacciono**.

Answer (score 0):

100% sure it is a spelling error.

> IO Piaccio
>
> TU Piaci
>
> EGLI Piace
>
> NOI Piacciamo
>
> VOI Piacete
>
> ESSI Piacciono

There is another word "Piacione", for definition check [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piacione/) that at plural it becomes "piacioni" and if mispelled it becomes "piaccioni"...

Comment: E che cosa aggiunge questa risposta a quelle già presenti, oltre a un po' di inglese vacillante?